# Move vim function definition window to bottom

Tags: vim

As you can see, vim pops up a window with definition of the function completion on the top (I don't know what its name is...), can I move it to the bottom?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the following line in your vimrc. ([Relevant help page](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27splitbelow%27))

```
set splitbelow
```

This causes all horizontal window splits to be put on the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Add below script to your vimrc file

```
"Preview window on the bottom of vim
function! PreviewDown()
    if !&previewwindow
        silent! wincmd P
    endif
    if &previewwindow
        silent! wincmd J
        silent! wincmd p
    endif
endf
autocmd BufWinEnter * call PreviewDown()
```